# Can’t import 'ConvBNReLU' from 'torchvision.models.mobilenet' while using GPU

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory

#### Problem

I’m following this tutorial to [train an object detection model for Lens Studio](https://github.com/Snapchat/snapml-templates/blob/main/Object%20Detection/object_detection.ipynb). I want to use a GPU to train the model, either Google Colab’s cloud GPU or my local through Jupyter.

When I try to import:

```
import torchvision
from torchvision.models.mobilenet import ConvBNReLU
from torchvision.ops import box_iou, nms
```

I'm getting the following error when the runtime is set to GPU.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-157e58f8c700> in <module>
     26 
     27 import torchvision
---> 28 from torchvision.models.mobilenet import ConvBNReLU
     29 from torchvision.ops import box_iou, nms
     30 

ImportError: cannot import name 'ConvBNReLU' from 'torchvision.models.mobilenet' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torchvision/models/mobilenet.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Expected behaviour:

It should just return imported.

#### What did I try:

I tried to run the code in a local environment using Jupyter and my local GPU and also connected the local runtime to Google Colab by using Jupyter to use the local GPU. In both cases, the error to import persists.

PyTorch set up in the local environment confirmed that the CUDA and usage of the local GPU are enabled and available for use.

When I set the runtime to CPU, everything gets imported and works as expected, and I can train and export the model.

Therefore, I believe the issue relates to the usage of GPU and

```
import 'ConvBNReLU' from 'torchvision.models.mobilenet’.
```

I’d be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: what version of `torchvision` are you using? try running with `-v` (verbose mode) it will tell you where python is going in search of the different `import`s. Is there a difference in the paths of the modules in GPU or CPU mode?

Comment: I think in current torchvision version you have `Conv2dNormActivation` instead of `ConvBNReLU`...

Comment: There are probably different pytorch versions on each of your runtimes, which causes the import differences.

Comment: My local environment shows `torchvision(0.14.1+cu117)`

Comment: I also followed the tutorial and installed the following dependencies in Google Colab.
`%pip install -q numpy opencv-python-headless==4.2.0.32 \ torch torchvision==0.5.0 xarray-einstats==0.1 \ albumentations==0.4.5 tqdm==4.43.0`
The error is the same in both cases.

Comment: @mskrftt so your local environment is `torchvision 0.14.1`, while the local one is `0.5.0` - I guess this is the issue. You are using a very old `torchvision` version on colab. Try updating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torchvision 0.13.0 :

```
from torchvision.models.mobilenet import ConvBNReLU
```

Torchvision 0.14.0 & 0.15.0 :

```
from torchvision.models.mobilenetv2 import Conv2dNormActivation
```

Change the function name call in your code too for either ConvBNReLU() or Conv2dNormActivation().

Comment: Thanks, @J.Jacobs! The 2nd line worked.

For additional context, I used this to install the packages:
`%pip install -q numpy opencv-python-headless \
    torch torchvision xarray-einstats \
    albumentations tqdm`

It doesn't return any compatibility errors and it works with:
`from torchvision.models.mobilenetv2 import Conv2dNormActivation`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from torchvision.models.mobilenetv2 import ConvBNReLU
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error.

`ImportError: cannot import name 'ConvBNReLU' from 'torchvision.models.mobilenetv2' (C:\Users\kryst\Documents\Coding\PythonEnvironments\TorchEnv\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\mobilenetv2.py)`

I tried running this one in my local environment in Jupyter.

Comment: @mskrftt this worked for me, `torchvision 0.13.0`.

Comment: Can you provide more information on where did you test it? Is it Google Colab or the local environment? I tried it in my local environment (no connection to the Colab) with `torchvision 0.14.1`, and for some reason still comes back with the error.

Comment: @mskrftt my local environment

Comment: Thank you, @Shai! I re-installed Cuda, and all packages, and it seems to be working!